# SQL Server: Appending the duplicate value with a number to differentiate the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, primary-key

I am writing a query to retrieve data using JOINs from three tables.

On the result I have primary column(Col1) repeating as below.

```
Col1 |Col2  |Col3
-----+------+-------
111  |1     |23
111  |2     |21
112  |1     |11
112  |2     |13
112  |3     |12
113  |1     |4
113  |2     |4
113  |3     |4
```

I want to modify the query in such a way that when the Col1 repeats,
I need a new column (Col4) to identify the difference as below, by adding an additional number sequentially to the exisitng value in Col1. This could be upto 5 as i will have five dieffrent values in col2.

The result will be as below. IS this possible.

```
Col1  |Col2  |Col3 |Col4  
------+------+-----+------
111   |1     |23   | 111
111   |2     |21   |1111
112   |1     |11   | 112
112   |2     |13   |1121
112   |3     |12   |1122
113   |1     |4    | 113
113   |2     |4    |1131
113   |3     |4    |1132
```

I am trying to retrieve data with one primary id having multiple entries in the result query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER()` can be used to number rows... you just need to handle row number = 1:

```
SELECT Col1
     , Col2
     , Col3
     , Col4 = CONCAT(Col1, NULLIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) - 1, 0))
FROM t
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1a2fa16925a6852f9228f493df3dd7e)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `concat()` with arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       concat(col1,
              (case when col2 = 1 then '' else col2 - 1 end)
             ) as col4
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your `col2` values aren't sequential, you can achieve your desired result using `row_number()`:

```
select results.*, 
       concat(col1, case when row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) = 1 then ''
                         else cast(row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) - 1 as char)
                    end) as col4
from results
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
111     1       23      111
111     2       23      1111                             
112     1       11      112
112     2       13      1121                             
112     3       12      1122                             
113     1       4       113
113     2       4       1131                             
113     3       4       1132
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=aac17bcfe9d67342c18d10478f5625df)